# Using lock-in amp to measure pulsed signal

Tags: sensor, pulse

I am working on a design of an acoustic resonator for sensing application,

I use an excitation field at a certain frequency (a), and measure the response of the sensor (b), for my application, I only care about the ringdown part to tune the resonance frequency, hence I'll be using the gated response (c),

This signal (c) will be connected to a lock-in amplifier to measure the frequency, how I can set the lock-in Amp to measure the pulsed signal only without averaging over time? more clearly, is there a way to time-gate the lock-in amp to measure the signal in the pulse window rather than averaging over time?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Your waveform is not all that conducive for lock-in amplifier processing. Any reason not to use a digital storage oscilloscope, or the like, to acquire and average successive decay transients?